# Laravel tagging system

Tags: laravel-5

I am developing an app where each post has number of tags. And another user subscribes to a tag and the user gets the tags only they have subscribed on. Currently I have made a

```
Tags table
-ID
-name
-slug
```

And another tags_users table

```
-ID
-user_ID
-tag_ID
```

So how do I get the subscribed post.Is there better way to manage the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While storing the datas

```
//Get the current user id
$user = Auth::user()->id;
//Getting the tag id from the form
$tagId = $request->get('tag_id')

$tag = new TagUser();
$tag->user_id = $user;
$tag->tag_id = $tagId;
$tag->save()
```

While fetching the datas

```
$tagusers = TagUser::get()
```